# AWS CDK CfnMapping value as list type in aws_cdk.aws_apigatewayv2_authorizers.HttpJwtAuthorizer's jwt_audience field

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

[The documentation for the underlying Cloudformation Mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html) says,

> The values can be String or List types.

If you use a list value mapping in a CfnOutput, you'll get an error.

```
# fails to deploy:
#  "Template format error: The Value field of every Outputs member must
#   evaluate to a String and not a List."

CfnOutput(
    self,
    "values",
    value=mapping.find_in_map(Fn.ref("AWS::Region"), "values")
)
```

Clearly the Mapping value is indeed a list.

However, if I try to use it as a list in [`aws_cdk.aws_apigatewayv2_authorizers.HttpJwtAuthorizer`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigatewayv2/CfnAuthorizer.html#aws_cdk.aws_apigatewayv2.CfnAuthorizer.JWTConfigurationProperty) , the stack can't even synth.

```
        mapping = CfnMapping(self, "Mapping",
            mapping={
                "us-east-2": { "values": [ "value1", "value2" ] }
            },
        )
        authorizer = aws_apigatewayv2_authorizers.HttpJwtAuthorizer(
            "HttpJWTAuthorizer",
            "auther",
            authorizer_name="JWT-Authorizer",
            identity_source=["$request.header.Authorization"],
            #jwt_audience=["value1", "value2"], # synth works
            jwt_audience=mapping.find_in_map(Fn.ref("AWS::Region"), "values"), # synth does not work
        )
```

Failure message is:

```
RuntimeError: Passed to parameter props of new aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigatewayv2_authorizers.HttpJwtAuthorizer: Unable to deserialize value as aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigatewayv2_authorizers.HttpJwtAuthorizerProps
├──  Failing value is an object
│      { '$jsii.struct': [Object] }
╰──  Failure reason(s):
    ╰─ Key 'jwtAudience': Unable to deserialize value as array<string>
        ├──  Failing value is a string
        │      '${Token[TOKEN.15]}'
        ╰──  Failure reason(s):
            ╰─ Value is not an array
```

Am I wrong in expecting this to work?  Since this issue happens at synth, this seems like a CDK issue.  I haven't tested it yet in pure cloudformation, but pretty confident it would work.

Reproduction: https://github.com/farrellit/cfn-mapping-test/blob/e7815503ceb7487ad722f7ea0a3afe5ed7b03b14/cdk_mapping_test/cdk_mapping_test_stack.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the token actually does resolve to a list, you can make CDK represent it as such using the [`asList` helper function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Token.html#static-aswbrlistvalue-options):

```js
// specifying the variable type explicitly here for illustrative purposes
const myValues: string[] = Token.asList(mapping.find_in_map(Fn.ref("AWS::Region"), "values"));
```

Comment: Ooooh thanks!  [that](https://github.com/farrellit/cfn-mapping-test/tree/as_list) passes the synth!  I'm really excited to use it today and then will mark this answer accepted once I prove it out in real life